# How to retrieving null Byte values from SQlite database to be used in if else statement?

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans, null, byte

I have a program that converts image files into bytes to save them to my database and then later retrieves them. This program is actually used for ID generation. Users can either save an image or not. When the user chooses not to save an image, the program should give their image a null value. The problem is it always give me a null pointer exception when there is no image. Are there any other ways to use a null byte to be used in if statement?

```
private void Members_TableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt){                                           
    int row =Members_Table.getSelectedRow();
    String Table_click=(Members_Table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());


    try{

     String sql ="select * from Members where No='"+Table_click+"' ";
     ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      rs=ps.executeQuery();
      if(rs.next()){

      String add1 =rs.getString("FName");
      ID_Front_FN.setText(add1);
      String add2 =rs.getString("LName");
      ID_Front_LN.setText(add2);
      String add3 =rs.getString("StdNum");
      ID_Front_SNo.setText(add3);
      String add4 =rs.getString("Course");
      ID_Front_Crs.setText(add4);

      byte[] BC_imagedata = rs.getBytes("BCImg");
      BC_format = new ImageIcon(BC_imagedata);
      ID_Front_BC.setIcon(BC_format);

      byte[] ID_imagedata = rs.getBytes("IDImg");
      if(ID_imagedata.equals(null)){ID_format=null;}else{
      ID_format = new ImageIcon(ID_imagedata);}
      ID_Front_Pic.setIcon(ID_format);


      }

    }catch(Exception e){

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] BC_imagedata = rs.getBytes("BCImg");
  BC_format = new ImageIcon(BC_imagedata);
  ID_Front_BC.setIcon(BC_format);

  byte[] ID_imagedata = rs.getBytes("IDImg");
  if(ID_imagedata == null){ID_format=null;}else{
  ID_format = new ImageIcon(ID_imagedata);}
  ID_Front_Pic.setIcon(ID_format);
```

Should be if(ID_imagedata == null) not if(ID_imagedata.equals(null)) that will always through a null pointer exception.  It is expecting an object as its input but instead you are passing null.